# OpenLayers 3.7 New Server Vector WFS with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, javascript, wfs, openlayers

I have recently updated from OpenLayers 3.0 to 3.7 and I noticed in the 3.5 update the Vector API has changed, I tried to alter the code as per the bottom section of code but i am getting the error below:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://PCNAME:8080/geoserver/example/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&re…-180803.92191974312,7068079.039279004,-170676.01567195728,7073596.83725834. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Code as per below:

```
var vectorFeatures = function(response) {
    var features = vectorSource.readFeatures(response);
    vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
  };

  var geoJSONFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
        var url = 'http://PCNAME:8080/geoserver/Example/ows?service=WFS&' +
        'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Example:layer_1&' +
        'outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:vectorFeatures' +
        '&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=' + extent.join(',');
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          success: function(data) {
            var features = geoJSONFormat.readFeatures(data);
            vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
          }
        }); 
      },
      strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running into the same origin policy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: what would be the easiest solution? I also didn't have this issue with older versions of OpenLayers so what's changed?

Comment: use a relative url or a proxypass on the webserver